# How to convert from a DOM Object to html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have taken a string of `html` in and have converted it to a `DOM Object`.

```
document.getElementById("textarea").value
var parser = new DOMParser();
var html = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');
```

How do I take the `DOM Object` that I created and convert it back to `html`?  Could you please show an example how I could put it on an `html` page?

Comment: I thought that gave me a `DOM Node`?

Comment: By "convert it back to `html`", do you mean convert it back to a string?

Comment: I want to be able to use it on my page again.  I thought that would be convert to `html`, but maybe I could just use a `String`?  If that would work, then that would be fine.

Comment: `html.documentElement.outerHTML`

Comment: the `DOMParser.parseFromString` returns a `Document` object.  At that point you can use methods like `querySelector()` and `getElementById()` or reference properties like `innerHTML` and `textConent`.  You can clone nodes and detach nodes.  At that point you have a `Document` you can manipulate.  There are any number of ways to get those parsed elements into your document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `HTMLDocument` that `parseFromString()` gives you, you can retrieve the its [`documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) and then that element's `innerHTML`.

```
console.log(html.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

---

Note that the markup may become *normalized* to make it a valid document, so you may end with more than you started:

```
var markup = '<span>Foo</span>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(markup, 'text/html');

console.log(doc.documentElement.innerHTML);
// "<head></head><body><span>Foo</span></body>"
```

Or, have corrections made for you:

```
var markup = '<table><div>Foo</div></table>';
// ...

console.log(doc.documentElement.innerHTML);
// "<head></head><body><div>Foo</div><table></table></body>"
```

Comment: Or worse yet, you could get unexpected behaviour as the result of invalid markup. (e.g. `<p>This is a test<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul></p>`)

Comment: If you use `innerHTML`, you won't get the enclosing `<html>`, so you should use `outerHTML`. If you don't want the added elements, you can use `doc.body.firstElementChild.outerHTML` or `doc.body.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be creating an entire Document, not sure if that is intentional. But, this should work with that you have now:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var html = parser.parseFromString('<b>ok</b>', 'text/html');
document.write(html.body.innerHTML);
```

Comment: How to convert a node to an HTML string though?

`var node = document.createElement('span')`;
Now i need this to be a string : '<span></span>', can we do this?